# Angular mat-icon scaling own svg

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to insert an mat-con to a button, which is part of a user-defined component.

```
`<button mat-button>
  <mat-icon svgIcon="jenkins" class="material-icons md-10"></mat-icon>  
  Jenkins
</button>`
```

The CSS-file of my component looks like that:

```
.material-icons.md-10 { font-size: 10px; }
```

But when I open my page it looks like that:
[Wrong size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbb5t.png)

It should be the jenkins-logo (http://jenkins.io) as a svg-graphic. But if I change the font-size the size of the picture doesn't change. The only thing I see is a little part of it.

How can I resize the icon or scale it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody is interested.

The solution of G. Tranter might be right, but didn't work here.

My icon wasn't square. I scaled it and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the width and height of the icon and/or the line-height in addition to the font-size:

```
.material-icons.md-10 { 
    font-size: 10px; 
    width: 10px; 
    height: 10px; 
    line-height: 10px; 
}
```

You *might* need to add the `!important` modifier (can't remember).

Comment: Now the icon is gone. Don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

The only way that I could successfully rezise a SVG material icon was by using the "transform: scale(x)" approach. It seems angular isn't changing SVG's viewbox size based on CSS attributes or container size.

Answer (score 1):

When using a custom svg-icon you need to use the `height` property in order to change the icon size.

```
.material-icons.md-10 {
     height: 10px;
 }
```